# SyntaxError: invalid syntax | Prediction

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

relatively new to python and trying to predict sales. I worked my way to this point in the process, and hit a wall. Please help if you can. what am I doing wrong? Btw, i'm working in python 3.

Code:

## reshape y_pred

```
y_pred = y_pred.reshape(y_pred.shape[0], 1, y_pred.shape[1])
```

## rebuild test set for inverse transform

```
pred_test_set = []
for index in range(0,len(y_pred)):
    print np.concatenate([y_pred[index],X_test[index]])
```

pred_test_set.append(np.concatenate([y_pred[index],X_test[index]]))

## reshape pred_test_set

```
pred_test_set = np.array(pred_test_set)
pred_test_set = pred_test_set.reshape(pred_test_set.shape[0], pred_test_set.shape[2])
```

## inverse transform

```
pred_test_set_inverted = scaler.inverse_transform(pred_test_set)
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-259-19ec122fada5>", line 7
    print np.concatenate([y_pred[index],X_test[index]])
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're truly using python 3, the `print` is now a function call rather than a statement. In other words, you need parentheses:

```
print(np.concatenate([y_pred[index],X_test[index]]))
#    ^                                             ^
```

The following transcript shows this in action:

```
>>> print 1
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print 1
          ^
SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(1)?
>>> print(1)
1
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Python 2 syntax, but running Python 3.

In Python 3, you should use the `print` function, like this: `print()`

In your case, the code snippet should be:

```py
pred_test_set = []
for index in range(0,len(y_pred)):
    print(np.concatenate([y_pred[index],X_test[index]]))
```

Comment: Thank you all! Very helpful